# One page site - images overflow on responsive versions

Tags: html, css

I've put together a one page site but am having problems with the top section.

It's fine on a desktop, but on any other device the three main photographs on the section stack, instead of the section expanding to allow this, the images just overflow (or are hidden if using overflow hidden property).

I'm not sure what the issue is that's causing this and would be grateful for your guidance.

Here's the html:

```
<!-- Jumbotron -->
<section class="jumbotron" id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main-photo" id="header-photo">

        </div>

        <div class="transparent-box" style="padding-top: 3%;">
            <img src="images/logo.png" style="width: 100%;"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" style="padding-top:5%">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <figure class="round-outline">
                            <img class="round-photo img-responsive" src="assets/photo1-sm.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="round-caption-bg"></div>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <figure class="round-outline">
                            <img class="round-photo img-responsive" src="assets/photo2-sm.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="round-caption-bg"></div>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <figure class="round-outline">
                            <img class="round-photo img-responsive" src="assets/photo3-sm.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="round-caption-bg"></div>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">


                    <a href="#quote-one" style="color: #d5b17c;">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-2x pulsate-opacity chevron"></i>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- End of Jumbotron -->
```

and the css:

```
/* ==========================================================================
Jumbotron Section
========================================================================== */

.jumbotron {
    padding: 100px 0 60px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: transparent url('../images/black-red-background.jpg') no-repeat top center;
    background-size: auto auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.jumbotron .container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? It's a bit hard to tell what's going on without seeing the actual images.

Comment: Is this how it looks for you? 

http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/jrRVgj

Comment: Sorry @PaulRedmond I've only just seen this. The website is [link](http://www.holliedevillier.com)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then the problem is your `col-md` classes cause breakpoints at the MD size which is tablets lower.

Change `<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-offset-1">` to `<div class="col-xs-4">`

And the other 2 `<div class="col-md-3"` also to `<div class="col-xs-4">`

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you. That wasn't what I was looking for but it's a great fix to the problem regardless. I was looking for a way to ensure that, when the images stacked on tablet and devices, the 'jumbotron' section got bigger (i.e. increased in height) so that all the images were visible. Is there a way to do this? I've already implemented your fix - just wondering if the other way is possible too. Thank you

Comment: What jQuery are you using to change the opacity on scroll? If this answer has helped please do vote it up and mark it as the correct answer if you've used it :)